# VBA code to pass username & password

Tags: vba, sendkeys

I'm trying to update some data into a SharePoint document and while trying this in local environment I do not face any issue.

But when I try to do the same in virtual desktop, I couldn't make it. I'm being populated with Windows Alert to key-in username & password. I've tried using 'SendKeys' for this scenario, but it doesn't make sense.

```
....
SendKeys "abc\ATX123",5
SendKeys "Password1",5
SendKeys "{ENTER}",5
....
```

This snippet is just passing 'ENTER' without entering ID & Pwd. Can anyone suggest me some possible solution, please?

Comment: maybe you have to target the correct fields. Enter is "global" I'd say, but the others are not

Comment: Can you share some sample please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I've found a way to achieve this requirement,,,,, bit indirect, but that was the only way I could find at the end.

What I did is simple - just created one windows scripted file 'Logon.vbs' to handle that popup screen and called the vbs in VBA.

Refer to the sample below, if you're looking for something like this:

Windows Script:

```
'Creating an script object
Set oWSH = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'Activating alert screen    
oWSH.AppActivate ("Windows Security")

'Passing the value UserName/UserID
oWSH.SendKeys "USERNAME"     'ensure to complete the username with apropriate domain e.g., abc/A123456

'Changing the focus to password textbox
oWSH.SendKeys "{TAB}"

'Passing the value password
oWSH.SendKeys "PASSWORD"

'Clicking enter to complete the screen
oWSH.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

'Releasing the script object
 Set oWSH = Nothing
```

VBA code to call the VBS script - Logon.vbs:

```
Shell "WScript C:\Users\ABC\Desktop\Logon.vbs", vbNormalFocus
```

Comment: +1 because now you will accept your own answer, please, so this question is not listed as unanswered anymore

Answer (score 0):

First of all you'll want to `SendKeys "yourString", Boolean`. As I know the `SendKeys` command wants a `True` or a `False` as second input.
You could also try "tabbing" from a field to another:

```
SendKeys "abc\ATX123", True
SendKeys "{TAB}", True
SendKeys "Password1", True
SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
```

if the first one didn't get get written, maybe the focus is on another component of the userform. Try "tabbing" to find out if your "Username" textbox is yet activated as the UserForm appears. In case it isn't you could also try to set some focus

Comment: Nope, after including 'True' also it didn't work,,,, and I've ensured that the focus is on Username textbox and Password textbox when the SendKeys passes the curresponding value... actually the logon screen is not any UserForm or any other type, it's 'Widows Alert' username & password pop-up screen.... any other clue please?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that UserForm (or Windows Alert) is somehow an object. Can you please try to debug your code so when that form shows up you run a search on the objects to find that one? If you can find it, the fields "Username" and "Password" will for sure have a name, therefore you'll be able to address them.