# Using MSXML in a VBA script to pull website data

Tags: excel, vba, msxml

I have the following code from http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2011/03/08/get-data-from-website-that-requires-a-login/#comment-60553

```
Sub GetTable()
Dim xml As Object ' MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim htmlDoc As Object ' MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim htmlBody As Object ' MSHTML.HTMLBody
Dim ieTable As Object
Dim clip As DataObject

Set xml = GetMSXML

With xml
      .Open "POST", "https://web.site", False
      .send "username=myname&password=mypassword"""
End With
With xml
      .Open "POST", "https://web.site/anotherpage", False
End With
Set htmlDoc = CreateHTMLDoc
Set htmlBody = htmlDoc.Body
htmlBody.innerHTML = xml.responseText

Set ieTable = htmlBody.all.Item("report")

    'copy the tables html to the clipboard and paste to teh sheet
  If Not ieTable Is Nothing Then
        Set clip = New DataObject
        clip.SetText "<html>" & ieTable.outerHTML & "</html>"
        clip.PutInClipboard
        Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial "Unicode Text"""
    End If

End Sub

Function CreateHTMLDoc() As Object ' MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set CreateHTMLDoc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
End Function

Function GetMSXML() As Object ' MSXML2.XMLHTTP
On Error Resume Next
  Set GetMSXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
End Function
```

Using this code I am attempting to access the site web.site and pass it a username and password to login, before proceeding to another page on the site, before copying the content of a table (results) into sheet1 of the excel workbook.

I have tried to debug this using f8 but without the visual browser that I would get if I were to follow this page http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2011/03/08/get-data-from-website-that-requires-a-login/ 
then its a bit difficult to see exactly what is happening and where it is failing.

Comment: You can write out the response for starters or use an API tester such as Postman to see what the server response is.

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate on writing out the responses?

Comment: Debug.Print xml.Status, xml.responseText

Comment: 1. Ensure you're POSTing your credentials to the correct URL, 2. Services/websites that require log-in usually have some means of client/session management. Check the 'Set-Cookie' header in the server's response, ensure you include it in subsequent requests (especially once you've logged in) -- as that cookie is associated with your session. 3. It might be helpful to open an Internet browser, open the developer tools (in Chrome you can do this by pressing `F12`) and monitor requests that appear under the `Network` tab as you manually log in -- to see the requests that need emulating.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code to assist you go onto the site, if you have any questions then just leave a comment on my channel https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hfAhmae4iqA ;

```
Dim IEe As InternetExplorer
    Dim doc, element
    Set IEe = New InternetExplorer

    IEe.Visible = False 'make true if you want to the internet explorer 
    IEe.Navigate "YOUR WEBSITE"

       Do While IEe.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until IEe.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

Set element = IEe.Document.getElementByID(INSERT ELEMENT ID) 'RIGHT CLICK ON WEBSITE AND SAY INSPECT ELEMENT CLICK THE MOUSE ICON AND THEN CLICK THE TEXT BOX WHERE THE PASSWORD OR USERNAME SHOULD BE INSERTED 

element.Value = "USERNAME"

Set element = IEe.Document.getElementByID(INSERT ELEMENT ID) 'THE FIRST IS FOR USERNAME THE NEXT FOR PASSWORD 

element.Value = "PASSWORD" 'remember storing a password in a macro is not safe
```

Comment: Quick question - are you just answering as many questions as possible to get the link for your youtube channel out there?  Why not add your channel to your profile and if people like the answers you're giving they can investigate further.  At the moment it's starting to feel like spam.  If I'm wrong, then I apologise.  Just that you're answering questions from 4-5 years ago - like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30916287/excel-vba-i-get-a-prompt-windows-security-when-accessing-an-url/60704420#60704420)

Comment: i have no intention to spam from questions that are from so long ago, just poviding insight where i can help if any one has a similar problem and comes across the thread