# Entering password for Windows Security while automating IE using VBA

Tags: windows, vba, excel, security, internet-explorer

I am trying to scrape some data off an intranet website created by a 3rd party and send an email depending on the data.  I did this in Excel with VBA since my machine is locked down and don't have Powershell or any other scripting language.

The issue is the website requires a login using a Windows Security dialogue box.  I've searched for hours and nothing is working. SendKeys in VBA does not work as the security box takes over and halts VBA. This almost worked: [VBA code to pass username & password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24879914/vba-code-to-pass-username-password).

The problem is when I scheduled it (task scheduler), sometimes the password (username is already populated) didn't go into the security dialogue and it is going to Word or whatever else is open.  I don't think "Windows Security" is the actual name of the window (though that is what is in the title).

Edit- Adding some of the code:

```
   Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
   IE.Visible = True

   CreateObject("WScript.Shell").AppActivate "XYZ.net - Internet Explorer"

   URL = "https://XYZ.aspx"
   IE.Navigate URL
   Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
   Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

   HWNDSrc = IE.HWND

   SetForegroundWindow HWNDSrc
   IE.document.getElementById("overridelink").Click

   Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:08"))
   Shell "WScript H:\data\excel\Logon.vbs", vbNormalFocus
```

Comment: Is entering the credentials needed to proceed further? You might want to try this in case it is not: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/windows-security-popup-asking-me-to-enter-my-login/530deb46-0962-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5

Comment: What's the context? Is it an automated IE instance you're running? Or using background ServerHTTP objects? Does this pop-up occur just when logging in to the site or is it on file download?

Comment: I added some of the code. It is an automated IE instance.  The pop-up is when logging in to the site and is required.

Comment: To add some more information, it seemed to work most of the time when I ran it from Excel.  When I Scheduled it, it rarely worked.  I closed everything to test it tonight.  Of course, Excel will still be open and could mess it up.