# Devtool is empty when inspecting it - cannot use FindElementById

Tags: html, excel, vba, selenium, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to automate web form data entry by using selenium VBA. We need to submit the forms on our organization SharePoint site, which requires us to log-in. I have already logged into the account. Please see the code below. Whenever I open the page (last step), there is a pop-up window asking me to enter the username and password again. I need to pass this step in order to get to the form that I want to enter all my information. I am not quite sure if this is an extra security that our IT team set up, but I could not inspect the page. I have included a screenshot here. I am hoping to inspect the pop-up window somehow so that I could use FindElementById. Thank you in advance for your reply.

[image]

```
obj.Start "chrome", ""
obj.Get "link"
obj.FindElementById("passwordInput").SendKeys ("password")
obj.FindElementById("submitButton").Submit
obj.FindElementById("idSIButton9").Submit
obj.FindElementByClass("reg-button").Click
obj.Wait ("1000")
```

`obj.FindElementByXPath("//div[@id='slwp_ctl00_ctl41_g_f6ad5b95_2503_406f_ad81_eb5b3f59cad2']/div/div[3]/ul/li[10]/div/a").Click`

Comment: The popup window is a built-in dialog so it doesn't have any elements. You can click its button using native VBA functions, maybe even WINAPI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue. However, in my case the dialog box was coming even before the login page was displayed.
The solution to the issue is given [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1001212/how-to-pass-question-mark-in-password-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-p)

Maybe something similar will help for you. Please try following steps.
I am not sure of the syntax in VBA. But these steps should help you.

1. Get the current URL. 
   In java this can be done by using the getCurrentUrl() method of WebDriver interface.
2. Modify this current URL to include username and password.
    The modified URL should be of in the following format:
          http://username:password@example.com/

   In java, this can be done by using the various methods of String class,
3. Submit the modified URL.
   In java this can be done by using the get(String URL) method of WebDriver interface.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried it, but it doesn't seem to work in VBA. It gave me a different error- invalid argument. (session info: chrome =80.0.03987.106 driver info: chromedriver = 80.0.3987.106) I have uploaded the screenshot in the question. I at least know the name of the issue and know what to search. I am trying to understand Windows Script in this post now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24879914/vba-code-to-pass-username-password. But thank you again for your detailed explanation.